# How to assign the drop down value based on the Text value of another column in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

I have created a custom list in sharepoint 2010 which contains two columns.

One column is single line of text.

Second column is dropdown which contains 4 values (q1, q2, q3, q4).

- If the text of first column contains as( jan or Feb or Mar) the
  dropdown should automatically select as q1.
- If the text of first    column contains as( Apr or may or jun) the
  dropdown should    automatically selected as q2.
- If the text of first column contains    as( jul or Aug or Sep) the
  dropdown should automatically select as    q3.
- If the text of first column contains as( Oct or nov or dec) the
  dropdown should automatically select as q4.

How can I achieve this requirement?

Comment: Is there any reason the second column is a DropDown and not a simple calculated field?

Answer (score 0):

you can consider making your first field as dropdown as well and make this 2 dropdowns as cascading dropdown. here is a good [Reference](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns)

Comment: Hi Ranjoe, Thanks for your Valuable information.But i could not able Change the single line of text column to dropdown.In the single line text colum, the user may enter as 8-Jan.if that fields contains Jan we need to assign as Q1.

Comment: then try this link for that *http://spjsblog.com/2010/06/15/cascading-dropdowns-in-sharepoint-text-fields-populated-by-lookup-in-another-list-version-2/* there is also a link that with his previous version. you can try to look into those and i think essentially those are the concept you are looking for